# Referring to the Four Seasons of Japan

Tags: usage

To say **"Four Seasons"** in Japanese would you say:

**Shiki** しき or **Yottsu no kisetsu** よっつのきせつ or will either do?

Comment: @JACK Please do not try to answer questions with comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both mean "four seasons", but よっつのきせつ is a mere combination of よっつ ("four") and きせつ ("season"), whereas しき is a dedicated word for that concept. Arguably, しき can be seen as a more "beautiful" or "colorful" word that has a stronger/vivider association with the beauty of changing nature, seasonal events, and so on. よっつのきせつ may be preferred when you need to emphasize the number *four* for some reason (for example, "Draw four icons that correspond to each of the four seasons").